# Horizontal Scroll View working unexpectedly

Tags: java, android, horizontalscrollview

I am trying to create a calculator. I am working in the latest Android Studio. Like in calculators, all new tokes(numbers, operators) should be shown in the right and if the field is larger than the display, it should scroll to the latest token. I have already browsed and found a way to do the same.
  The code for the same is:

```
private void scrollRight() {
    horizontalScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView);
    ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = horizontalScrollView.getViewTreeObserver();
    viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            horizontalScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            horizontalScrollView.scrollTo(entry.getWidth(), 0);
        }
    });
 }
```

`scrollRight` is called by a onClick event which checks if a token is entered and calls this.

Everything is working perfectly, i.e. on every new token the scroll bar is scrolling to the end. But if I try to scroll to the beginning manually, it no longer works. After this every time a new token is pressed, the scroll bar first moves to the end and then back to the beginning.
The only option that remains is to restart the program. I tried debugging the `OnGlobalLayout` function but the debugger loses all frames while stepping out from the function, so it is difficult to know what exactly is making the scroll bar go to the beginning.

GIF to show the problem:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gukRy.gif]

Please Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
horizontalScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                horizontalScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);
            }
        });
```

And call `findViewById` only once in onCreate.

Comment: This looks better than the 'ViewTreeObserver' method and am going to implement this. Now for every token, the scroll bar moves from left to right and for the next token, it moves from right to left. Again this is initiated only if try to scroll manually. Also, I have used the 'findViewById' only once in 'onCreate'. That was a hindsight on my part!

Comment: Yeah! The fullscroll method works. No idea the reason the scrollTo method is not working. Anyway, thanks for the quick reply.